# Get blog post from postlist array october cms?

Tags: laravel, twig, octobercms

I am creating a blog page, the post list page is in the form of different sized images. I need to be able to style each post list item individually so need to be able to access the post list array with twig and get posts.

So for example, when accessing a featured image from a post you can use:

```
    post.featured_images[0].path
```

I would like to do this but to select the first post in list of posts.

Comment: Hi, your question is goind to be downvoted if you don't provide some codes and examples of what you want to achieve. It's your first post so I suggest you edit his question before anything. And welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Hi @El_Matella is this better? Do you know how I might go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you want to do with the first post you can access the first post using the iteration variable in the loop.

There are few iteration variables in Twig, I usually use `loop.index` variable.
For example:

```
{% for post in posts %}

    {% if loop.index == 1 %}
        {{ post.title }}
        {# this is the first post title #}
    {% else %}
        {{ post.title }}
        {# this is others posts title #}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

And as you go if `loop.index == 2` so you can access the second post. If it equals 3 you can access the third post etc.

Another alternative would be `loop.first`.

```
{% if loop.first %}
{# It goes here if it's the first record of the loop #}
{% endif %}
{% if loop.last %}
{# It goes here if it's the last record of the loop #}
{% endif %}
```

To learn more about Twig's loop variables: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

Comment: Thank you Ahmed! That is exactly what I needed!